# Unity File Lens Giving Useless or No Results

Tags: unity, 11.04, files

I just installed Natty fresh on my laptop, and for the purposes of this experiment, I have one file on my system. My Downloads, Documents, Music, etc are all empty, but Pictures contains one file named "tornado.png". If I simply hit the super key and search through that main lens, I don't get results for "to", "torn", or even "tornado" -- only for "tornado.png". And, if I search using the Files Lens (Super+S), I get no results at all, even for "tornado.png".

Is this not getting indexed properly? What's going on?

Comment: possible similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39405/deeper-unity-search-indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file lens displays results based on files that you have actually opened. It does NOT search a full index of all your files.

At a technical level the results come from a tool called Zeitgeist rather than Tracker.

If you search for files useing Super +F you have the added advantage of having search results arranged by how recently you opened the files.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when switching to Unity, and thought that not having proper indexing in 2011 is a bit weird. So I made a little data provider for the file lens which queries Tracker to ge the results.

It's available here: https://github.com/hoheinzollern/tracker

And the instructions to get the thing running on your system are in the wiki: https://github.com/hoheinzollern/tracker/wiki

Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with an empty dash.  Check out this fix: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1853156.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.