# Search results in Unity are always empty

Tags: unity-dash, search, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

This is a bit similar to [Unity File Lens Giving Useless or No Results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33717/unity-file-lens-giving-useless-or-no-results) but worse - I have a relatively clean install of 11.04, upgraded from 10.10, and I don't seem to have any lenses at all, only "shortcuts"; and I never ever get any results, regardless of what I type in the dash search box.

Yet zeitgeist is installed OK and works as evidenced by the Activity Journal.