# How can Ubuntu Dash find files & folders which are not in my home folder?

Tags: files, unity-dash

Though through dash i can find all my file & folders which are in my home folder partition of my hard disk. But in one of my hard disk partition i have kept all my movies, & i cant never find them. If they appear they only appear as recently played, but i want them to show permanently, like they show from my videos in home folder.

Answer (score 1):

This thread might help in your understanding of how this works:

[Deeper Unity search indexing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39405/deeper-unity-search-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

The unity-lens-files has had a fix release in unity-lens-files (5.6.0-0ubuntu1) precise. On the date of this post this release hasn't appeared as an update.

Check the version of the unity-lens-files is below unity-lens-files (5.6.0-0ubuntu1). Instructions can be found [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-help-test-an-improved-unity-files-lens/) how to install the testing ppa to get all files (at least under home) appearing in lens file searches.

N.B. This is a testing ppa, and should be used with caution.

Comment: Well i guess there is some miscommunication. As i am not asking for deep searches & search in folders of home folder. I am not talking about home folder whatsoever. I am talking about files outside home folder. Lets say i have divided my hard disk in three partitions A B & c & i have chosen A to install Ubuntu, B to keep all my movies & all my songs in c folder. Now dash can find all my files which are there in folder (A) but is there any way it could show my movies n music files which i have kept in my B & c partition of the same hard drive.

Comment: Feel free to downvote :). I'd assumed they were mounted permanently, and perhaps misread how locate was being used.

Comment: The reason why you only see the files you recently opened is because the mechanism for indexing files is Zeitgeist which does just that. The unity-files-lens uses slocate to index additional files. You can try to add a symbolic link to your home directory, and if that doesn't work, a hard link to your videos. Google will tell you how. Finally, this solution might still work if the unity-lens-files uses a global slocate database which you can manually set. :P