# Unity - dash cannot find files (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus, unity-dash

I have noticed since a while that dash cannot locate some files that I have on my machine, mainly from Dropbox.
We can see below that I have a .pdf file called "TcII professor". If I search for the string "Professor", Nautilus will return me what I want:
[image]

However, when I launch the dash to look for the same string (Professor), I got no result:
[image]

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like no categories are enabled (though not sure how this is possible as it should fall back to defaults). What happens if you click "Files & Folders" on the right?

Comment: I agree with you, although all the "files and folders" category was selected before I typed the search text. Still, I also clicked this again after inputting the search text and it could not find the file.

Comment: Does it find any files at all (e.g. for other inputs and directories)?

Comment: it does find files that were recently opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Unity by default uses [Zeitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_(free_software)) for searching files, which is why only previously opened files are found.

You can try to install [Unity FileSearch Lens](https://launchpad.net/filesearch-lens) for full file search, or follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/43667/166291) (a bit dated though).

Comment: thanks, it worked by typing  `sudo updatedb -U $HOME`.