# Unity-dash - disable Zeitgeist as search engine permanelty

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash, zeitgeist

Following up [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885354/unity-dash-cannot-find-files-ubuntu-16-04), I've managed to locate any file on my computer (and not only those which had been recently opened) by inputting the following command on the terminal

```
sudo updatedb -U $HOME
```

However, I have noticed that I have to run this command every time I log in. Does anyone know a way to permanently disable Zeitgeist such that I don't need to run the command every time I want to find my files?

Comment: You can make this command a little script that works on startup

Comment: yes that's indeed an option. Yet I am wondering if there's any other option and also why this is happening only in this computer.

Comment: If you disable `Zeithgeist` you'd loose more functionality than just your updates on your `home` folder.